# Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call - when doing setTimeout in React component library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I am trying to build a React component library.

The code runs fine in the component library project, but as soon as I install the package a particular component is not working and giving the following error message.

```
index.js:1 Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I am using `"react": "16.9.0"` and `"react-dom": "16.9.0"` in both my component library and app which i've installed it in.

The component looks like this, it's not very complicated so all I can think is it's to do with the setTimeout function. Which may be throwing the error due to the example in the documentation of calling from within another function.  I've tried wrapping in a useCallback but this hasn't worked, does anyone have any ideas?

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

[image]

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MuteOn from '../../../static/images/icons/btn-mute-on.svg';

const AttendeesMuted = () => {
  const [showWarning, setShowWarning] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.setTimeout(() => setShowWarning(false), 3000);
  }, []);

  if (showWarning) {
    return (
      <div className='sg_attendees_muted'>
        <p>
          Please note, you have joined this conference muted, to unmute press
          the <img src={MuteOn} alt='muteBtnImg' /> button
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

export default AttendeesMuted;
```

I thought it may be due to point 3, that there may be more than one copy of React in the same app.  I am new to writing component Libraries, but have both `React` and `React-Dom` in the dev-dependencies and also in peer-dependencies in the component library project.

** UPDATE **

I have tried the suggestion of adding react to the externals of the React component library.

```
externals: {
    'react': 'react',
  },
```

However, when I then load in the component I then get this error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

[image]

Comment: Make sure you exclude React from  your component library bundle by defining externals.

Comment: Ahh brilliant thank you, this is what I will not be doing, I am not setting it as an external.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are using the library in your react application. If you define React in externals, publish it to registry and then install it in your application, it shouldn't have a problem at all but if you are installing it using npm link, then most likely there are two React versions getting bumped. One solution for that is to install React in the library from  your application using `file:../your app/node_modules/...` or another is to use a monorepo with `lerna` or `yarn workspaces` where packages are hoisted to the top.

Comment: Ahh brilliant thank you, this is what I will not be doing, I am not setting it as an external. I am not in at the moment but I will check when I get back and then accept the answer.

Comment: I've tried this and can't get anything to work.  I've tried to add React to the externals but it does then not work.

Comment: I have added a description above?  What I am I doing wrong here?

I really want it so that my parent app doesn't have to worry about the child component, the child component to just just the parent apps React